# How to send email in app from UI Label (Swift 2 IOS 9)?

Tags: ios, swift, email

With manipulation of this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

I have a table view displaying people, when the cell is clicked the user is redirected to another view showing their picture and their email. **I want to be able to have the user click on the email address and email them**. I have researched and found similar tutorials 
https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/08/25/send-email-in-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-with-swift/

The problem with the tutorial above is when test running the new code the ios simulator pops up an error and wont show the composed email (Maybe a Glitch?)and If the simulator did not give an error I dont know how to display multiple emails based on which person the user selected. Any help on solutions to this problem or any alternative will be great Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**The simulator will crash when you try to open the mail. Try it on an actual device instead.**

To compose a mail do the following
Add these to your class
`MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` and `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, this is the function called when you presses a row in your tableView. Do the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let candy = candies[indexPath.row]
    var mail: MFMailComposeViewController!

    // yourArray is the array that you use to populate the tableView
    // .mail is the variable in the object (I´m assuming you´re using objects in your array)
    let toRecipients = [candy[indexPath.row].email]
    let subject = "Feedback"
    let body = "<br><br><p>I have a \(UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName).<br> And iOS version \(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion).<br</p>"

    mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mail.setToRecipients(toRecipients)
    mail.setSubject(subject)
    mail.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: true)

    presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The delegate methods below if you need to use them

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

    func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
        switch (result.rawValue) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        case MessageComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        case MessageComposeResultSent.rawValue:
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but the button is placed in a view controller

Comment: How would you know which email address the user has selected if the button is placed outside? Isn´t it better to just let the user click on the mail and then send the mail?

Comment: The button is inside the viewcontroller which is linked to a protoype cell. Depending on which populated cell the appropriate email will be listed. I followed the ray wenderlich tutorial if you want to see the basis how the app works. 

I manipulated his code by puting
`candies = [
Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Bar", email:"email@gmail.com")`

Comment: If I may suggest you, I would have done it as I wrote in my answer. In that way you will only have to select a row and do the mail code and set candies[indexPath.row].email as recipient and you will open a new mail with the recipient preselected.

Comment: Sorry I new to coding, could you provide some sample code?

Comment: @Chase add the code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function in my answer I have updated it so it gets data from candies now. Good luck.

Comment: Im sorry to ask again but can you update the code to work in a view controller?

Comment: Svend me a link to your project if you want me to take another look at it @Chase